# Can you ask two nested IF questions for one mail merge response?

Tags: microsoft-word, email, merge, mail-merge

I am comfortable with the IF question but the response has a he/she which I want to be gender specific.

Can you have an AND command between two IFs? { IF {MERGEFIELD "Field" } = "value" AND { IF {MERGEFIELD "Title" } = "Mr." "he is under a contract." ""}{ IF {MERGEFIELD "Field" } = "value" AND { IF {MERGEFIELD "Title" } = "Ms." "she is under a contract." ""}

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your outcome by nesting IF fields.

[image]

This IF test effectively says if Field = value (TRUE) then do something, otherwise (FALSE) do something else.

If Field = value is true, then the TRUE step is then to test to see if the Title is Mr.  If it is Mr. (TRUE) then add text, otherwise (FALSE) we want to test for Ms.  Effectively, this means is like an AND because Field = value AND Title = Mr.

The final IF is for the (FALSE) result of the Mr. test, and looks for Ms.  If Title = Ms. then (TRUE) insert text, otherwise do nothing.  Again, this is like an AND because the text is inserted only if we have Field = value AND Title = Ms.  If the test fails, (FALSE), do nothing ie ""

The final "" means do nothing if the Field <> value ie (FALSE).